# Tools and practices for small group collaboration?

Tags: collaboration

I will be starting a senior design project in a week with 2 or 3 other engineers.  We are electrical engineers but we will need to do some coding for our project.

Right now, I think using Google Code + Visual Studio + AnkhSVN is a good solution on the code side.  We also need to:

- Maintain design documents
- Have a smooth way of communicating

Would you recommend anything in particular beyond a central network storage, and e-mail?

Edit: We are not going to set up or configure anything.  I would rather just pay for cheap (

Comment: I'd recommend using a DVCS, rather than SVN (no offense, SVN guys, it  was great for its day!).  Even on single-person projects I greatly appreciate the added flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a good wiki such as Atlassian's Confluence.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a great list of [Collaborative Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collaborative_software).  I think a decent content management system would be essential for maintaining design documents (especially over plain network storage).

Answer (score 0):

You might try **[Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/)** , the basic plan is enough for you already.